# Assymetric signing algorithms for JWT signing

Tags: jwt, authorization, public-key-encryption

JWT noob here, so sorry if this is a stupid question: Is it possible to sign JWTs with assymetric keys/certificates/etc?

If I understand JWTs right, the idea is that the client can authenticate to the server with them because they contain a signature the server can check.

All the examples I've seen online rely on the same secret key for creating and verifying the JWT.

Now, if I wanted to issue JWTs for different servers and did it like that, I'd have to give them my secret key (probably one for each server), and they'd be able to issue JWTs with it. I might not want to allow that. Also each server could only verify JWTs that were created specifically for it or one with the same key.

On the other hand, I do know that things can be signed with assynchronous algorithms in such a way that you can verify the signature with a public key, but sign stuff only with the private key.

That would solve the problem, because each server that wants to accept JWTs my server signed only has to download my public key. Does such a thing exist in JWT?

Comment: Yes, of course, you can sign with **asymmetric keys**, maybe you did not find the answer because of the wrong term, it's **asymmetric** what you need to search for and you should be able to find many tutorials and also [answers on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjwt%5Dasymmetric) explaining that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean an asymmetric algorithm, not an asynchronous algorithm.

The short answer is yes - you can use an asymmetric algorithm like RS512 to sign a token with a private key and then validate it with the matching public key. This way you don't have to share the secret outside of the service that signs the token.

Note that different libraries may support different algorithms, so make sure to check which algorithms the library you use supports. [JWT.io](https://jwt.io/) has a pretty comprehensive listing of which libraries support which algorithms.

Comment: you are quite right about assymetric via assynchronous... I must have been very tired at that time...